# Rails 4.1 is enum functionality working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I am going crazy just trying to do the simplest of things with the new rails enum (I know it's still in beta)

Anyway I am trying to use the rails console to pull all enums on an object (since it's not working in code) e.g.

```
class Interaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum outcome_type: { hot: 1, neutral: 2, cold: 3 }
end
```

Then I run the rails console and try Interaction.outcome_types

According to the documentation this should be fairly simple and straight forward.

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

I get only errors :/

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `outcome_types' for #<Class:0x007fb5e595ebb8>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you use the call to that `enum`?

Comment: Interaction.outcome_types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the documentation you refer to is of edge Rails, and you probably use Rails `4.1.0.beta1`, which is a beta release, and not edge.

`4.1.0.beta1` was released on December 18, 2013 (https://rubygems.org/gems/rails). The commit that makes the code you are trying to use work is from January 14, 2014: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/b242b2dbe75f0b5e86e2ce9ef7c2c5ee96e17862

and it also has the method that worked before this commit documented:

```
+    Before:
+
+        Conversation::STATUS # => { "active" => 0, "archived" => 1 }
+
+    After:
+
+        Conversation.statuses # => { "active" => 0, "archived" => 1 }
```

---

So I suggest either updating to edge Rails, or using, in your case, `Interaction::OUTCOME_TYPE` instead of `Interaction.outcome_types`. It works for me, with a fresh test app that uses 4.1.0.beta1 and implements your exact model code.